# How can I write the output inside the folder of a S3 bucket using Lambda fuction

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am coding in Python Lang. in AWS Lambda and I need to write the output which shows in output logs in a folder of S3 bucket. The code is,

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
ouput_data = b'Checksums are matching for file'
client.put_object(Body=ouput_data, Bucket='bucket', Key='key')
```

And now I want to add Checksums are matching for file and then I will need to add the file names. How can I add

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Or what specific feature do you need to add to this code? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: I have to change a folder content in S3 bucket through Lambda function, The output_data we change in the code will also impact into the change of the content of the folder which is present in my S3 bucket in .txt format